# How to reinitialize a custom control on a Tab Control page when the page is selected

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

In the following code, I am placing custom controls on each page of a TabControl. When first loading the TabControl, all the custom controls are initialized and layed out.

All the custom controls can update the source database.

How do I reinitialize each custom control when the tab page it is on is selected?  (i.e., The MedicalRecords custom control will update the database, to which the Nursing custom control will have to reinitialize, etc.).

TIA

```
<TabControl>
        <TabItem x:Name="AppointmentsTab" Header="Appointments and Scheduling">
            .........      
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem x:Name="MedicalRecordsTab" Header="Medical Records">
            <mr:MedicalRecords/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem x:Name="NursingTab" Header="Nursing Service">
            <nurse:Nursing x:Name="ccNursing"/>
        </TabItem>
             .......
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```

Comment: by _"to reinitialize"_ you mean _"to get updated data from DB"_?

Comment: @vasily.sib Yes. Each control has direct access to the Database and is able to modify the pertinent records. I need these modifications to be seen in the other controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you initialize your controls, but you could for example handle the `Loaded` event for a control and perform any re-initialization logcin in there:

```
ccNursing.Loading += (s,e) => { /* re-initialize */ };
```

The other option would be to bind them to a shared `DataContext`/view model.

Comment: The custom controls are being correctly initialized when the tab control is created by the CLR (xaml). The problem is how to re-initialize them after they are loaded. I've come to the same conclusion that I would need a shared DataContext. The approach, though, I think I'm going to try is to use events for signaling...I'll see how that works. Thanks.